# How to show shadow over scroll view items in react native

Tags: react-native, css-position, native-base, box-shadow

I'm using native-base's Content to scroll and i want a fixed button on bottom when scrolling. How can i show the shadow of fixed button over scroll view Items **like this**.
[image]

**But what i achieve is this**
[image]

> My Code

```
    <Container>
      <Content>
       ...
      </Content>
      <View style={styles.footer}>
        <Button style={styles.footerBtn}>
          <Text>{strings('consultant_profile.book_an_appointment')}</Text>
        </Button>
      </View>
</Container>

//Css
footer: {
    padding: 20,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.23,
    shadowRadius: 2.62,
    elevation: 4,
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to implement such gradient effect in react-native because of the limitation of it on `shadow`. For Android API 27 or below, you cannot even change the color of `elevation` in Android by using `shadowColor`.

For your situation, I would recommend you to use [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient#transparent-gradient).

After installed the package simply place the below component at the top of your button, it might do the trick.

```html
<LinearGradient colors={['rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)']} {...otherGradientProps} />
```

Comment: You can change the color with the shadowColor property.

Comment: Is there no other way to archieve a "real" shadow, not just a gradient?

Comment: Thank you, I just notice that shadowColor is available for later Android version!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve the kind of "real" shadow that you are looking for.
From my understanding, React Native respects the design philosophy of the platforms (also in a way to adapt to them). 
The reason why the term "elevation" is used for Android instead of "shadow" because it aligns with Material Design (https://material.io/design/environment/light-shadows.html#light). 
In Material design, the elevation has strict definition since it is imitating how real life elevated object works with shadow.
So it is not possible to do what you want with shadow in RN.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to following style to the button styles:

```
shadowColor: "#000",
shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: 2,
},
shadowOpacity: 0.23,
shadowRadius: 2.62,
elevation: 4
```

If it's not working then please share more of the your component code so it will be easier to try help you out.

Comment: Not worked, Kindly have a look into my code I've pasted above.

Comment: Try add 'margin: 5' to the button style and please let me know if it changed anything

Comment: I added margin to footer View but not worked, i want shadow on footer View not on button, as you can see in image

Answer (score 0):

You can animate items opacity to get something similar look.